# I get an error when I try to start a project in debug

Tags: java

When i try to run my project in debug mode, i get immediately an error. 
This error shows up only in debug mode, when i run my project it works 
how it should.

My java and javac version are the same.

i'm using JDK 1.5 for my project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KImmU.png)

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at `enter code here`sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:133)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Can be you more specific please

Comment: see the post I linked: it contains a question about the same/similar error (UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number)